# Problems installing and booting to ubuntu

Tags: grub2, software-installation, uefi

Hardware:
msi meg ace x570 mobo, newest bios flashed,
ryzen 5950x,
2 adaptec 71600 sas controllers,
x1 version of the asus gt710,
240gb kingston ssd, will be 30 more samsung drives on the adaptecs eventually.

First turn on went fine, went into the Bios and set everything up, namely x8 + x8 bifurication for the adaptec cards.

Took a 20.04 usb key I've used over a dozen times in the past 6 months and tried booting to it. The live cd got hung up after grub and I found that its likely due to needing safe mode graphics until I get the proper nvidia driver installed. Second time round I chose safe mode at grub and successfully installed ubuntu. Yanked the key and hit enter and restarted like normal. Boot never even gets to grub, just sits at a blinking cursor. I though ok maybe something is wrong with that install or key so I pulled a new image, made a fresh usb key, and installed again. Same thing happened though, no grub just black screen with cursor again. Dug around online and saw some stuff about UEFI not working so I changed the bios to allow legacy and tried installing again. The live cd got to the purple splash but I never saw a grub screen to select safe mode and the graphics do very weird things and never gets to the installer, just spams text about noveou default driver errors on a very messed up screen.

I installed a keyless windows 10 pro to make sure all my hardware was fine and it worked flawlessly minus the fact that windows is complete trash.

I have never had such issues with Ubuntu acting so strange but I really need to get this working...

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI, that's all.

Comment: Standard desktop does not normally support RAID. Are you installing server version? Did you install optional proprietary drivers to get nVidia driver installed. Otherwise you have to boot with nomodeset boot parameter until you install nvidia driver. Only use UEFI, do not even turn legacy on. New systems are starting to obsolete legacy mode & then new drivers will not be available in the future. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI I do not know RAID, but have seen most use a boot drive and then have data on RAID drives.

Comment: Im not using BIOS raid option. The adaptec controller has its own bios and handles the raid arrays itself. Additionally removing the adaptec sas card does not change anything. I did try nomodeset when booting to the uefi live usb key which worked just like safe mode graphics. However I do not ever see grub before the lock up when booting to ubuntu installed on my ssd so nomodeset can not be entered. I tried using the live usb key to edit and update grub with nomodeset and a timeout of 10 but nothing changed. Just boots to black screen with a cursor and hangs.